# Fazer div fechar ao clicar fora dela

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma `li` com o id `buscaBT`, quando eu clico nela, ela deixa uma div dentro dessa `li` (`formularioBusca`) como `display:block`, até aí, tranquilo, tudo funcionando. Fiz assim:

```
$( "#buscaBT" ).click(function() {
    $( '.formularioBusca' ).css('display','block');
});
```

Minha dúvida é: eu quero que quando a pessoa passe o mouse fora dessa div, ela feche.

Comment: Seria isso : [jquery mouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseout.asp) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso precisa adicionar um oscultador de evento para o `mouseleave` associado a essa classe. Exemplo:

```
$('.formularioBusca').on('mouseleave', function(){
    // correr código aqui
});
```

Pode depois esconder diretamente com

```
this.style.display = 'none';
```

ou fazer uma animação para fechar com

```
$(this).slideUp();
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/8tL9y/

Comment: funcionou 100%. :D

Comment: Isso vai fazer com que ao passar o mouse fora da div, a mesma fecha, tem como fazer ela fechar ao clicar?

Comment: @SOSTheBlack nesse caso precisas só disto: http://jsfiddle.net/8tL9y/6/ (se não tiver acertado faz uma nova pergunta pf)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Click</a>
    <div>teste</div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li div{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $('li div').toggle();
});
$('li div').mouseleave(function(){
        $('li div').toggle();
});
```

**Versão jQuery: 1.11.0**
**Exemplo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4acZR/**